# document.getElementById("items_" + i) is null

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    document.getElementById("items_"+i).checked=true;
}
</script>
```

With the following HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="items_1" name="myitems" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="items_2" name="myitems" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="items_3" name="myitems" value="3" />
```

I get an error saying:

```
document.getElementById("items_" + i) is null.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9):

The first index in your for loop will be zero.

Do you have an element with the id `items_0` ?

That's likely what's causing your problem. Set the initial value of `i` to `1`

Secondly, you want to make sure that your Javascript code executes after the DOM has loaded.

I recomend you look into using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as this makes it so much simpler to do these kinds of things.

Comment: also make sure the script is executed *after* the elements are created in the DOM.

Comment: no, there is no items_0. even if i tried : for(var i=1; i<3; i++), i get the same error

Comment: this is some very old code that i don't have time to convert to jQuery. otherwise, i would. thx

Comment: As long as you make sure that you execute the JS after the DOM has loaded you'll be fine. http://jsfiddle.net/5TZvg/ (JSFiddle automatically loads the JS section after the DOM has been loaded)

Comment: Is this your exact code btw? If it is, do you really need to set the checked property with JS?

Comment: Did my answer help you @FALCONSEYE? Please hit the accept button if this is the case :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well your code looks like it's first iteration is pointed to i = 0 so it's trying to find an input tag with the id of 'items_0'.

Here is a JSBin that shows the code working correctly:

http://jsbin.com/amonel/edit

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
$('#items_'+i).attr("checked", true);
```

Comment: You previously commented that you didn't have time to convert to jQuery, yet here you are answering your own question with—*GASP*—jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

```
var VanillaRunOnDomReady = function() {
    // code to execute after DOM has loaded  
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {        
        document.getElementById("items_" + i).checked = true;
    }  
}

var alreadyrunflag = 0;
if (document.addEventListener) {    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        alreadyrunflag=1;
        VanillaRunOnDomReady();
    }, false);
}
else if (document.all && !window.opera) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" id="contentloadtag" defer="defer" src="javascript:void(0)"><\/script>');

    var contentloadtag = document.getElementById("contentloadtag");

    contentloadtag.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (this.readyState=="complete"){
            alreadyrunflag=1;
            VanillaRunOnDomReady();
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout("if (!alreadyrunflag){VanillaRunOnDomReady}", 0);
}
```